# Unresolved external, trying to use static variable c++

Tags: c++, class

I have class World in world.h:

```
class World
{
public:
    static Ground* ground;
};
```

and in another class in a function I try to use the static variable ground like that:

```
#include "Node.h"
#include "World.h"
void Node::Foo()
{
    Ground* ground = World::ground;
}
```

and also in world.cpp i have:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "World.h"

static Ground* ground = new Ground(10, 10);
```

But i get the following errors:

- LNK2001  unresolved external symbol "public: static class Ground World::ground" (?ground@World@@2PAVGround@@A)
- LNK1120  1 unresolved externals

[image: image of the errors:]

Comment: Please include the errors as text, not images

Comment: `static Ground* ground = new Ground(10, 10);` -> `Ground* World::ground = new Ground(10, 10);`

Comment: This question might be a duplicate, but it's worded infinitely more clearly than the original question was. +1 for OP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
static Ground* ground = new Ground(10, 10);
```

You're missing `World::` there, so you're defining a completely unrelated variable that just happens to have the same name. You should have this:

```
Ground* World::ground = new Ground(10, 10);
```

Comment: I indeed did have to add `World::`, and I also had to remove `static` from the cpp file.

Comment: Good point. I edited my answer to reflect that.